# Remap mousewheel to LClick when another key is held down AHK

Tags: click, key, autohotkey, mousewheel

I'm trying to remap my Mouse Wheel Up to send Click or Key while another key is pressed down.

Ex. key is pressed down && scrolling up == LClick
key is not pressed down == scrolling up scrolls up.

I am brand new to AHK so as much help as possible would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Generally we don't write code for you, but will gladly help with specific programming problems. In cases like these, we like to see what efforts you've made to answer this yourself (Google, help documentation, previous attempts, etc.) AHK can be powerful and is relatively easy to get started with. The help file is great and walks you through the basics, so I'd recommend spending some time with it. The specific part that will answer your question is here: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm Note that `WheelUp` is what's used for scrolling up with the mouse wheel.

Comment: I managed to make this but it lags a lot and I don't know why; It works but not very well:
 #if, GetKeyState("XButton1", "P")
    *WheelUp::click
#if

#if, GetKeyState("XButton1", "P")
    *WheelDown::click
#if